# What is Key in Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm new to this nuget package and confused with the **Key** class.

Here is my code base on [Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1/) document:

```
public long InsertMessage<T>(T iEntity) where T : IEntity<T>
{
    var keyFactory = _db.CreateKeyFactory(Kind);
    var entity = iEntity.ToEntity();
    entity.Key = keyFactory.CreateIncompleteKey();

    using (var transaction = _db.BeginTransaction())
    {
        transaction.Insert(entity);
        var commitResponse = transaction.Commit();
        var insertedKey = commitResponse.MutationResults[0].Key;
        Logger.Info($"Inserted key: {insertedKey}");
        return insertedKey.Path[0].Id;
    }
}
```

All I do is to create an entity and create an incomplete key, send to the server, then get the populated key back from server.

I think the **key** is served as **unique identity** to the entity.

If there's misunderstanding please correct me.

I can get entities by Query as below:

```
var query = new Query(Kind)
{
    Filter = Filter.Equal("key", key),
    Order = { { "created", PropertyOrder.Types.Direction.Ascending } }
};
foreach (var entity in _db.RunQueryLazily(query))
{
    list.Add(entity);
}
```

But I don't know how to use the key I got when inserted to get the unique entity by `Filter.Equal("key", key)`.

The example shows the **Key's structure** is:

```
{
    "partitionId":
    {
        "projectId": "projectId",
        "namespaceId": "namespaceId"
    },
    "path": [
    {
        "kind": "kind",
        "id": "id"
    }]
}
```

**Here I conclude the question I have:**

1. What is **Key** class for?
2. What is Key's path and why it's array?
3. Is `id` the unique key to the entity?
4. How to `Query` by `Key` and `Id`?

Thanks for reading and please don't mind my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key is a unique identifier for a document. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) says it best:

> Each entity in Cloud Datastore has a *key* that uniquely identifies it. The key consists of the following components:
>
> - The *namespace* of the entity, which allows for multitenancy
> - The *kind* of the entity, which categorizes it for the purpose of Cloud Datastore queries
> - An *identifier* for the individual entity, which can be either
>
>   - a *key name* string
>   - an integer *numeric ID*
> - An optional *ancestor path* locating the entity within the Cloud Datastore hierarchy
>   An optional ancestor path locating the entity within the Cloud Datastore hierarchy

The "ancestor path" part is the reason there's an array in the `Path` property - a fully qualified key is a namespace followed by a sequence of [path elements](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.Key.Types.PathElement.html), each of which consists of a kind and "integer ID" or "string name" part.

So for example, you might have a library application. That has shelves and books. Ignoring the namespace part, a particular book might have an ID with path elements of:

- Kind=Shelf; Id=1 (numeric ID)
- Kind=Book; Name=xyz (string name)

Another way of thinking of this is like an alternating sequence of collection and document names, e.g. "/shelves/1/books/xyz". That's how [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) represents its document IDs.

Any one path element doesn't have to be unique, but the complete path is unique. There's no real concept of querying by "key and ID" - you can look up a complete key (e.g. `DatastoreDb.Lookup`) or include a parent key as an ancestor path query.

Comment: Since the key is unique, can't I use it to get the unique document?