# GCP DataStore entity using ancestor and path

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

The post question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941376/what-is-key-in-google-cloud-datastore-v1).

The library I use is this - [Google Cloud Libraries for .NET](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet).

Now I have no problem on simply usage of single entity, but I have encountered another problem while I try to retrieve the identity of the entity by .

The Problems are listed below:

1. How to insert an entity with ancestor by using the library?
2. After I inserted the entity with ancestor, how to get the identity of the entity inserted?
3. How to use `PathElement`?

My English ability is poor, so please don't mind and forgive me for I'm not fully understood the documentation.

If there's something improper or not described well, please tell me.

Anything will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "How to use `PathElement`?" What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: If I use the sentence `What scenario can use PathElement and how to achieve that` will make the question better?

Comment: I feel difficult to ask these questions and I'm in this trouble for a long time. Hope I can understand the operations' usage of DataStore's entities.

Comment: You use `PathElement` when you want to look at individual elements in a path, basically. It's not really a specific question to answer. I'm writing an answer for the first two. (Note that normally you should stick to one question per post. In this case the first two can easily be answered together though.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll be careful next time when ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an entity with an ancestor, you just need to make sure that the key you provide has that ancestor. If you're happy to specify the name part of the new path element, the simplest way of creating the new key is to call `Key.WithElement` on the ancestor's key, but with a new path element.

If you want to generate a key, it's slightly harder at the moment as there's no method on `Key` like `WithElement` to create a new key that has an incomplete final element. You can easily write your own extension method to do that though.

The inserted key is returned when you insert an entity, by the `Insert` method. Here's a complete example, first creating a "shelf" entity, then three "book" entities as children of that:

- One with a specified name in the key
- One with an incomplete key so that the server fills in the ID, created by an extension method
- One with an incomplete key generated by a `KeyFactory`, to demonstrate that option.

Code:

```
using Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1;
using System;
using static Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.Key.Types;

static class KeyExtensions
{
    // Useful extension method to create an incomplete "child" key
    public static Key WithIncompleteElement(this Key key, string kind)
    {
        Key ret = key.Clone();
        ret.Path.Add(new PathElement { Kind = kind });
        return ret;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string projectId = "YOUR-PROJECT-ID-HERE";
        DatastoreDb client = DatastoreDb.Create(projectId);

        Entity shelf = new Entity
        {
            Key = client.CreateKeyFactory("shelf").CreateIncompleteKey(),
            ["genre"] = "fiction"
        };
        Key shelfKey = client.Insert(shelf);

        // Insert a book specifying a complete key
        Entity book1 = new Entity
        {
            Key = shelfKey.WithElement("book", "potter1"),
            ["title"] = "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone"
        };
        Key book1Key = client.Insert(book1);

        // Insert a book by creating an incomplete key with the extension method
        Entity book2 = new Entity
        {
            Key = shelfKey.WithIncompleteElement("book"),
            ["title"] = "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets"
        };
        Key book2Key = client.Insert(book2);
        Console.WriteLine($"Inserted key: {book2Key}");

        // Insert a book by creating an incomplete key with a KeyFactory
        KeyFactory keyFactory = new KeyFactory(shelf, "book");
        Entity book3 = new Entity
        {
            Key = keyFactory.CreateIncompleteKey(),
            ["title"] = "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban"
        };
        Key book3Key = client.Insert(book3);
        Console.WriteLine($"Inserted key: {book3Key}");    
        Console.WriteLine();

        // List all the books    
        var books = client.RunQuery(new Query { Kind = { new KindExpression { Name = "book" } } });
        Console.WriteLine("All books:");
        foreach (var book in books.Entities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{(string) book["title"]}: Key={book.Key}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know when the child is set, child's `Key.Path` will be? Take a child which has 3 ancestors for example, is [0] show be great-grandparent or child? If [0] indicates great-grandparent, then [1] as grandparent, [2] as parent and [3] as the child, Is is correct?

Comment: I would like to know how to get the `numeric identifier` by using `Entity.Key.Path` because we have to store the value to lookup this entity next time.

Comment: I accept this as the answer because it answered most part of my question. If there're more details about the usage of  ancestor path, that will be great enough to get award bounty.

Comment: @TerryWei: Each element of the path has a `PathElement` that has an ID if it was specified. So you could use `long id = book3Key.Path.Last().Id;` for example. As for "details about the usage of ancestor path" - I can't add more details as there's no specific question. Stack Overflow is good for answering specific questions, it's not good for open-ended "Please tell me everything there is to know about topic X" questions.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. `long id = book3Key.Path.Last().Id;` is what I actually need! What I need is just that the child is the last `PathElement` of Path and the order is from ancestor to child. And the question 3 is nearly answered as you mention that its usage. Great thanks to the whole answer(s) that I totally understand these parts of usage of entity.

Comment: One more question which is not related to this question. Why I can only award my bounty after 24 hours? I feel inconvenient that I could not award your great help immediately.

Comment: @TerryWei: It's so that plenty of users get a chance to look at bounty questions.

Comment: Thanks you very much!